# How to generate the continuous sequence which sum up equal to N

Tags: algorithm, math

Given a number N and generate an Arithmetic Progression having difference of 1 so that after summing up to finite element gives the number N
for example:

```
For Example:
N=10
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 =10
N=20
2+3+4+5+6 = 20
N=30
4+5+6+7+8 = 30
```

N < 1000000

Comment: Not all N has such a summation form. E.g., 2 and 4.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about maths.  If you want us to think of it as a programming problem show us your code.

Comment: @Memming Yes they do. `2 = 2` and `4 = 4` (i.e. `N` can be considered an arithmetic progression of just 1 number).

Comment: @memming Sorry I couldn't think of edge cases. Dukeling is right here.

Comment: Actually, if we consider the solution of @Dukeling the simplest solution for all cases would be `N` itself. Hence I assume the largest number in the sum must be less than `N` (in which case there is not always a solution). Or perhaps that we are looking for the longest sequence?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Indeed, though you could probably make the assumption that you should find the smallest such progression.

Comment: Also, if `N mod 2 == 1`, then you can just return `(n+1)/2, (n-1)/2` for a non-one number sequence. I really think we should be looking for the *longest* sequence. For example, with `N = 15`, should we return `[7,8]` or `[1,2,3,4,5]`?

Comment: Solution for this problem is intended to have the longest sequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let T be the number

So N(N+1)/2 = T in your first case where N=4

N(N+1)/2 - K(K+1)/2 = T in your second case where N=6 & K=1

N(N+1)/2 - K(K+1)/2 = T in your third case where N=8 & K=3

So you solve for N basically that is by multiplying & reducing you get

N^2 + N - (2T + K^2 + K) = 0

Applying quadratic formula for N that is 
N= (-b + sqrt(b^2 - 4ac))/2a

So we get,
N = (-1 +- sqrt(1 + 8T + 4K^2 + 4K))/2

N has to be positive so we can remove the negative case

Therefore N has to be equal to 
N = (sqrt(8T + (2k+1)^2) - 1)/2
You can iterate from K=0 till you get a natural number N which will be your answer

Hope it helps, Iam trying to find a better way as iam doing this(appreciate the interesting problem)

Comment: This seems like you can do it fairly efficient (linear complexity?!). Improvement may be to start with K = N/2 (or something smarter) and then do a search in log(N) steps.

Comment: This is excellent, though I'm interested in how you'd determine if N is a natural number?

Comment: n=(int)n that would be the easiest way wouldn't it? in javascript i would use n==parseInt(n) & n>0

Comment: @Ram Thanks Ram. Excellent approach

Answer (score 7):

1. Start with sum = 0.
2. Let 1 be the current number.
3. Add the current number to the sum.
4. If `sum > N`, subtract numbers from the first number added to the sum until `sum <= N`.
5. Stop if `sum = N` (success).
6. Increase the current number.
7. Continue from step 3.

You'll just need to remember the first number added to the sum for step 4, which you will increase by one as you subtract it from the sum (thanks Niko).

As an optimization, you can also use [a formula (`n(n+1)/2`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) to add numbers in batch rather than adding them one by one (in case `N` is large).

**Example:**

N = 30

```
Sum = 0
Add 1 -> 1
Add 2 -> 3
Add 3 -> 6
Add 4 -> 10
Add 5 -> 15
Add 6 -> 21
Add 7 -> 28
Add 8 -> 36
36 > 30, so:
  Subtract 1 -> 35
  Subtract 2 -> 33
  Subtract 3 -> 30
Done.
```

Comment: You'll probably want a terminating condition for fail cases as well, i.e. "stop once you would add the current number N+1".

Comment: @G.Bach It would always terminate when only N is in the sum.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Maybe something about the running time? Should be O(n log n) considering we have up to 2n additions with log n bits worst case.

Comment: @G.Bach Yes, if you consider addition a `log n` operation, then it's `O(n log n)`.

Answer (score 2):

Let `N = pq` where `p` is an odd positive integer and `q` is any positive integer.

(1) You can write `N` as sum of `p` consecutive integers, with `q` as the middle value.

(2) And if both `p` and `q` are odd (say, `q = 2k+1`), you can also write `N` as sum of `2p` consecutive integers, with `k` and `k+1` in the middle.

For example, let `N = 15 = 5 x 3`.

If we choose `p=5`, then following rule (1) we have `1+2+3+4+5 = 15`.
Or by rule (2) we could also write `(-3)+(-2)+(-1)+0+1+2+3+4+5+6 = 15`.

We can also choose `p = 3` to get `4+5+6 = 15` and `0+1+2+3+4+5 = 15` too.

Answer (score 2):

```
int NumSum(int val)
{
    int n = 0, i = 0, j;
    while (n != val)
    {
        n = 0;
        j = ++i;
        while (n < val)
            n += j++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

No fancy maths, just the easy way of doing it.. Returns number to start counting from.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a trick method & i think it might work.

Lets say number is 10 then start a sequence from n/2 that is 5
Now the sequence cannot be

5+6 since 10>11 so we have to work backwards also 5 is the upper limit of numbers we need to consider since numbers like 6+7 etc will exceed 10 so the last number(highest) of the sequence will be 5. 
moving backwards 5+4=9 < 10

5+4+3=12 > 10 so remove first element kinda like a queue.

So for 20 we have
start = 20/2 = 10

1. 10 + 9 = 19 -> do nothing
2. 10 + 9 + 8 = 27 -> remove first element that is 10
3. 9 + 8 + 7 = 24 -> remove 9
4. 8 + 7 + 6 = 21 -> remove 8
5. 7 + 6 + 5 = 18 -> do nothing
6. 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 = 22 -> remove 7
7. 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 = 18 -> do nothing
8. 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 = 20 -> Answer we need

I guess this is a variation to the accepted answer but still thought i could add this as an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, every odd number is the sum of an AP length 2 because `n = floor(n/2) + ceil(n/2)`.

More interestingly, a number with an odd divisor d is a sum of an AP length d (with difference 1) around `n/d`. For instance, 30 is divisible by 5, so is the sum of an AP around 6: `30 = 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8`.

A number with no odd divisors is a power of 2. While `1 = 0 + 1` and 2 = `-1 + 0 + 1 + 2`, larger powers are not the sum of any (non-trivial) arithmetic progression. Why? Suppose `2**m = a + (a+1) + .. + (a+k-1)`. Sum the series `= k (2a + k-1) / 2`. k must be odd or even, but either choice contradicts the sum being a power of 2.